# Using a variable (or field) inside a new component

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to make a functionality of tabs at the top of my page with the possiblity to add a tab.
I am using a hook to check which tab should be displayed on screen, therefore the tab component checks if its index is the chosen index.

like so:

```
const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(1);
const toggleTab = (index:number) => {
    setToggleState(index);
  };
return...
<button
          className={toggleState === 1 ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}
          onClick={() => toggleTab(1)}
        >
          Tab 1
        </button>
```

In order to make a new tab I wanted to add a button that creates a new component and adds it to the screen. I tried doing it like this:

```
class topTab extends React.Component {
      index: number;
      constructor(index: number) {
        super(index);
        this.index = index;
      }
      
      render() {
        return (<button
          className={toggleState === {this.index} ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}
          onClick={() => toggleTab(this.index)}
        >
          Tab {this.index}
        </button>);
      }

  };
```

but I got stuck since the condition check pops an error:
"This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'number' and '{ this: any; }' have no overlap."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring an object, but not using a field name. While this is possible it is not if using the this keyword.

Declare the field name:
`className={toggleState === {index: this.index} ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}`

However based on the code you have provided you don't want an object anyway.
toggleState is a number so the expression will always be false.

You probably want this

`className={toggleState === this.index ? "tabs active-tabs" : "tabs"}`